# Objective-C method execution while object is deallocated - should I fix that?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In `methodA` of my view controller `VC1` another view controller's (`VC2`) method `methodB` is called in which `VC1` is deallocated. Then control returns to `VC1 methodA` which obviously crashes when `self` is used.

It is not obvious that the instance is deallocated, so developers may use `self` without knowing that they should not. From that perspective I'd like to fix the deallocation. However, I'd like to get some opinions whether or not such a situation is common or needs to be fixed ASAP a.s.o.

**Q1**: Is execution of deallocated object's methods somewhat common which one will encounter in typical medium projects?

**Q2**: Would it be acceptable, if comments are added, which warn the developer?

**Q3**: Are there any other recommendations / opinions?

The project is of medium complexity (about 200 classes of which 50 are view controllers). I'd like to get a feeling about how much effort I should invest to take care of such "deallocated method calls". If it would be one of my smaller pet projects, it would be rather easy to fix anything. However, with an inherited project which already went through a couple of hands, things are not so trivial any more.

**EDIT:**

**didFinish delegate scenarios:**

Thinking about it, I came across `didFinish` kind of delegate calls. Assume a master view controller (`MasterVC`) uses a slave view controller (`SlaveVC`) to do some work, keeps a strong reference to it and sets itself as a delegate for the `SlaveVC`. When the slave is finished, it calls `slaveVcDidFinish`. In `MasterVC`'s implementation of `slaveVcDidFinish` the strong reference to the `SlaveVC` is set to `nil`. So when the `slaveVcDidFinish` returns, it is `SlaveVC`'s responsibility to never use `self`, as it may have already been deallocated.

```
- (void) notifyDelegate
{
    [self.delegate slaveVcDidFinish];
    // From here on, `self` may be invalid...
}
```

This likely is relevant, when the `SlaveVC` is dismissed before the call to `slaveVcDidFinish`, as otherwise it cannot be deallocated because it is part of the view controller hierarchy.

**Q4**: Is my understanding of this `didFinish` scenario correct?

[/EDIT]

---

A few details, in case it is relevant:

1. `VC2` presents `VC1` and keeps a strong reference
2. `VC1` does its work and needs to present `VC3` for which it dismisses itself before
3. `VC3` does its work and delegates back to `VC1`'s `methodA`
4. `VC1`'s  `methodA` delegates to `VC2`'s `methodB`
5. `methodB` releases the strong reference to `VC1`, `VC1` now gets deallocated (`dealloc` is called), and control returns to `methodA`
6. `methodA` does a little more work and then returns

One way to do the little more work was to call methods on an object passed into `methodA` as parameter. That should work, as `self` does not play a role there.

Another way to do that work was to call a method of `VC1` using `self` which obviously causes a crash. So as long as one does not use `self`, everything should be fine.

Comment: Why you get `Objective-C method execution while object is deallocated`? You are not using ARC?

Comment: ARC is used - I was not expecting that VC1 is deallocated at that point at all, but obviously it is.

Comment: @Cy-4AH: When ARC deallocates an object, it calls its dealloc method (and the dealloc of the superclass etc. etc. ) if you have one and you can put whatever code you like into the dealloc.

Comment: @gnasher729, thank you, Captain.

Comment: Yes, indeed it's obviously strange. ARC retains all method arguments, except `self`. And it's odd, because actually self is first argument.

Comment: self is never retained (with the assumption that this would be a retain / release for _every_ _single_ _call_ and would slow things down). That's why you get a warning when you call methods on a weak object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should fix it, but based on what you are saying your app architecture must be to a greater or lesser extent wrong. You are trying to implement an algorithm distributed across view controllers that really needs an object that lives across the lifetime of the objects you are dealing with. Such needs a mediator object.

Actually I suspect you may not need to be implementing that algorithm at all and another approach that works better with how controllers are instantiated and how control gets passed around the app would work fine, but you haven't posted sufficient info for me to be able to advise on that.

However having said that, implementing an overarching controller could certainly be used to solve your problem. A good way to do this is often to subclass your current root view controller (or better still a subclass that implements a category you define). So for example, if it is a UINavigationController you are using, create UINavigationController subclass, change the class of it's representation in your Storyboard (assuming you are using storyboards) and do the work of coordinating display and dismissal of other view controllers in there.

Also check out the Mediator design pattern http://cocoapatterns.com/ios-view-controller-transitions-mediator-pattern/

As a note, generally these days you can avoid having any object properties for strongly holding view controllers. Usually the root view controller holds strong references to any view controller it needs to present, lazy invocation should be used to present view controllers that are not currently presented or stored in an existing navigation controller stack (which keeps the memory utilisation profile in good shape) and any other child view controllers can be added in to your view controller heirarchy using the addChildViewController: method in which case they are strongly held in the childViewControllers array property.

You may want a convenient name for a view controller, but actually I would recommend writing a small bit of code for as the implementation of any such property that will identify the controller you need from amongst those in the Apple supplied properties, and dynamically retrieve it. This may seem like hard work, but it's worth it and actually, paradoxically, decreases code complexity and helps ensure you stay working with the view controllers the way Apple intended. Doing anything else increases pain.

Using separate object properties for holding references to view controllers will usually only duplicate mechanisms the existing Apple classes already provide you with. Such unnecessary duplication increases code complexity and can introduce bugs and memory management issues (of the kind you are in fact describing).

Sorry this answer is quite general, but you are seeking an answer to the wrong question. From what you have said it's clear that at some level you need to address your app architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually VC2 is already a kind of overarching view controller. The names which I gave are placeholders - the names in the project are descriptive so that part is good. The project does not use storyboards, but has tons of xib files. The challenging aspect here is that some view controllers are reused in other context and I need to make sure, that I do not break those. So of course I can move forward, but I move a little slower :-)

Comment: Sorry didn't answer your direct questions;

Q1: Probably happens but bad style. 

Q2: That's for you to decide. The issue is if you forget they are there. I would do a massive multi line   //////////////////////// bar.

Q3: I would recommend changing the architecture and sorting this out. It will always be a pain. Usually the responsibility for view controller instantiation and dismissal can be changed around with fewer impacts than might be supposed, but it's difficult to say for your case without seeing the code.

Comment: My expectations match what you said in your answers, but I was not sure, whether there would be acceptable scenarios for Objective-C experts / gurus. I think that I need to fix the intermediate dealloc. As you mentioned, it will hurt again and again in the long run :-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree the architecture seems flawed but as you say it is inherited code and not trivially small maybe some compromises must be made.

I am thinking since self (or any instance variables or properties) cannot be called anyway perhaps you could make the methods you need to call class methods (+) rather than instance methods (-). Class methods are obviously safe to call without an object instance.

Comment: Unfortunately the methods are protocol implementations and used as delegates all over the place.